# Chromedp Package: How to get updated HTML source of the webpage which has dynamically loaded contents by using chromedp

Tags: go, web-scraping, web-crawler, headless-browser

I am trying to scrape the video links on the web page, https://www.tokopedia.com/chocoapple/ready-stock-bnib-iphone-128gb-7-plus-jet-black-garansi-apple-1-tahun-10?src=topads
There are links, which are getting generated through "webyclip" service which loads the data after the page is loaded. I want the updated HTML source of the page after all the JavaScripts and AJAX are loaded (Similar when we do "Inspect element" on a browser). How to get it done through the chromedp package (https://github.com/knq/chromedp). It is a headless browser for GoLang. Please help. I am a newbie in web scraping.

EDIT: It is not similar to the another question mentioned in the link. As this is specific to chromedp package. The one in the comments ask for how to/ what to use to scrape dynamic contents.

Comment: @TimCooper: This question is specifically about the chromedp package.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

After many attempts, Finally, I found the way and solved my query.
You can check my [GitHub](https://github.com/yogesh-desai/WebCrawlerTokopedia) repository for this query.
Thank you.

Comment: This is not useful at all, why does someone has to scrape through your code to find a solution with a problem. If you want to be helpful post the code here.